¿Como puedo mejorar el rendimineto de 3 left join a una misma tabla con muchos datos?
Buen dia estimados tengo unas tablas con muchos registros pero el problema radica en que, necesito hacer 3 left join a una misma tabla "personas_verificadas" porque traigo datos de parientes de la persona central por asi decirlo.
Existe alguna tecnica para acelerar la consulta (tabla temporal o vista, etc):
SELECT 
                       (SELECT count(*) FROM personas_verificadas pvr where condicion='reemplazado' and pvr.id2_operacion=pv.id2_operacion) as reemplazado,
                       o.id2 AS id2_operacion,
                       o.grupo AS NroGrupo,
                       o.fecha_y_hora_sistema AS FechaPedido,
                       ope_d.cuota_comercial,
                    
                    ..otros campos
                       pv2.suma_ingresos,
                       pv3.nombre_y_apellido AS nombre_y_apellido_pariente2,
                       pv3.documento AS documento_pariente2,
                       pv3.fecha_nacimiento AS fecha_nacimiento_pariente2,
                       pv3.suma_ingresos AS suma_ingresos_pariente2,
                       btpt3.tipo AS tipo_pariente2,
                       bcm3.categoria AS categoria_pariente2,
                       pv3.actividad AS actividad_pariente2,
                       emp3.razon_social AS razon_social_pariente2,
                       pv3.cargo_actual AS cargo_actual_pariente2,
                       pv3.actividad AS actividad_pariente2,
                       pv3.actividad_monotributo AS actividad_monotributo_pariente2,
                       pv3.domicilio_laboral AS domicilio_laboral_pariente2,
                       pv3.domicilio_monotributo_autonomo AS domicilio_monotributo_pariente2,
                       pv3.fecha_ingreso_laboral AS fecha_ingreso_laboral_pariente2,
                       pv3.fecha_inicio_actividades AS fecha_inicio_actividades_pariente2,
                       pv3.ingresos AS ingresos_empleado_pariente2,
                       pv3.ingresos_jubilado AS ingresos_jubilado_pariente2,
                       pv3.estado_habilitado AS estado_habilitado_pariente2,
                       bcm3.ingresos AS ingresos_monotributo_pariente2,
                       pv3.ddjj_ingresos AS balance_anual_pariente2,                        
                       pv3.suma_ingresos as suma_ingresos_pariente2,
                       pv3.suma_ingresos as suma_ingreso_pariente2,
                       bpr3.parentesco as parentesco_pariente2
                   FROM
                       personas_verificadas pv
                           LEFT JOIN
                       operaciones o ON o.id2 = pv.id2_operacion
                           LEFT JOIN
                       operaciones_datos ope_d ON o.id2 = ope_d.id2_operacion
                           LEFT JOIN
                       usuarios u ON u.id2 = o.id2_usuario
                           LEFT JOIN
                       basicas_estados bes ON bes.id2 = o.id2_estado
                           LEFT JOIN
                       concesionarias c ON c.id2 = u.id2_concesionaria
                           LEFT JOIN
                       tipos_trabajador tpt ON tpt.id2_persona = pv.id2
                           LEFT JOIN
                       basicas_tipo_trabajador btpt ON btpt.id2 = tpt.id2_tipo_trabajador
                           LEFT JOIN
                       empresas emp ON emp.id2 = pv.id2_empresa
                           LEFT JOIN
                       basicas_categorias_monotributo bcm ON bcm.id2 = pv.id2_categoria_monotributo
                           LEFT JOIN
                       personas_verificadas pv2 ON pv2.id2_persona_pariente = pv.id2 AND pv2.estado_habilitado = 1
                                               
                           LEFT JOIN
                       tipos_trabajador tpt2 ON tpt2.id2_persona = pv2.id2
                           LEFT JOIN
                       basicas_tipo_trabajador btpt2 ON btpt2.id2 = tpt2.id2_tipo_trabajador
                           LEFT JOIN
                       empresas emp2 ON emp2.id2 = pv2.id2_empresa
                           LEFT JOIN
                       basicas_categorias_monotributo bcm2 ON bcm2.id2 = pv2.id2_categoria_monotributo
                           LEFT JOIN
                       basicas_parentescos bpr ON bpr.id2 = pv2.id2_parentesco
                           LEFT JOIN
                       personas_verificadas pv3 ON pv3.id2_persona_pariente = pv.id2 and pv3.id2!=pv2.id2  AND pv3.estado_habilitado = 1
                           LEFT JOIN
                       tipos_trabajador tpt3 ON tpt3.id2_persona = pv3.id2
                           LEFT JOIN
                       basicas_tipo_trabajador btpt3 ON btpt3.id2 = tpt3.id2_tipo_trabajador
                           LEFT JOIN
                       empresas emp3 ON emp3.id2 = pv3.id2_empresa
                           LEFT JOIN
                       basicas_categorias_monotributo bcm3 ON bcm3.id2 = pv3.id2_categoria_monotributo
                           LEFT JOIN
                       basicas_parentescos bpr3 ON bpr3.id2 = pv3.id2_parentesco
                   WHERE .... DESC LIMIT 1,300;()


Esa es la consulta anidada, la uso para descarga un excel con informacion, pero, aunque le pongo un offset de 300 y voy iterando queda lenta. trabajo con Mysql y PHP.
No se si un stored procedure podria ayudarme trayerndo las relaciones solo si existen datos.
Por lo que entiendo cada persona verificada puede tener hasta 2 parientes asociados, por eso hace 2 left join anidados en esa tabla y otras tablas de detalle

¿Esos campos donde comparas sus valores tienen índice?  Normalmente eso acelera las consultas donde son usados.

Si tienen indices y son id alfanumericos

Es decir todos los id de las tablas tienen que estar indexados

Si los índices están puestos correctamente y tienes bien diseñado el modelo de datos (no redundancia de datos, usar el tipo de dato más adecuado para cada columna, relacion correcta entre las diferentes tablas, etc) no tendrás ningún problema aunque tengas que hacer varios JOIN. La cuestión es, ¿va lenta tu consulta actual? Si la respuesta es si, entonces puedes empezar con algo como EXPLAIN para determinar qué cosas se pueden mejorar.

Creo que no me has entendido.  Las tablas suelen tener índices primarios, pero yo te preguntaba por los campos que usas en las comparaciones, es decir, si para dichos campos has creado índices adicionales ya sea con PHPMyadmin o bien con una consulta del tipo CREATE INDEX.

Mis sugerencias:

Tablas con índices; esto no solo con las PK, sino también con las FK
y llaves candidatas.

Evitar usar subconsultas dentro del query:


    SELECT count(*) FROM
    personas_verificadas pvr where condicion='reemplazado' and
    pvr.id2_operacion=pv.id2_operacion


Te sugiero lo agregues como un LEFT JOIN (subconsulta claro)
finalmente es un COUNT y su agrupador es pvr.id2_operaciones...
esto de forma general, revisa bien el resultado esperado.

Que los campos usados en el LEFT, RIGHT... y demás estén indizados.


Es lo que puedo sugerirte incluir (no solo en esta consulta); y sí, tengo entendido (no soy DBA) los SP ayudan aunque la velocidad de la consulta depende no solo que el código este en la BD (como es con SP) sino cómo está construida.
